# How to pass the variable "s" to the is_fl_vowel() method?

Tags: python

How do I pass the variable `s` to my `is_fl_vowel()` method?

The code:

```
def is_fl_vowel():

  if (s[0] == 'a' or s[0] == 'e' or s[0] == 'i' or s[0] == 'o' or  s[0] == 'u' or s[0] == 'A' or s[0] == 'E' or s[0] == 'I' or s[0] == 'O' or  s[0] == 'U') and (s[-1] == 'a' or s[-1] == 'e' or s[-1] == 'i' or s[-1] == 'o' or  s[-1] == 'u' or s[-1] == 'A' or s[-1] == 'E' or s[-1] == 'I' or s[-1] == 'O' or  s[-1] == 'U'):
    return True
  else:
    return False

def main():
  s = input("Enter the text to be tested")
  if is_fl_vowel():
    print("Passes the vowel test.")
  else:
    print("Fails the vowel test.")

########################################################################
### Do not modify anything below here if you want the tests to work! ###
########################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

The error message when I type in my inputs:

```
Enter the text to be tested computer science
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 18, in <module>
  File "python", line 10, in main
  File "python", line 3, in is_fl_vowel
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: add it as a parameter `is_fl_vowel(s)`

Comment: You need to learn how to use function parameters. This should be in every tutorial.

Comment: @Daniil Kharlashko if your question has been answered please accept an answer so this question can be closed

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the string and the function needs to accept an argument.

```
def is_fl_vowel(s):
    return s[0].lower() in 'aeiou' or s[-1].lower() in 'aeiou'

s = input("Enter the text to be tested")   
if is_fl_vowel(s):
    print("Passes the vowel test.")
else:
    print("Fails the vowel test.")
```

Comment: `s[0].lower() in 'aeiou' or s[-1].lower() in 'aeiou'`

Answer (score 0):

add it as a parameter: `is_fl_vowel(s)`